# Mysql time range query using extract

Tags: mysql, select, extract

I'm trying to get an mysql query similar to `date_trunc` in psql.

Unfortunate Mysql do not have `date_trunc` function and I found I can use extract instead in Mysql.

What I want to do is write a script which i will run let say 10 minutes past each hour but I want to only select data from begin of an hour till end of this hour.

For example I will run script 12:10 and I want to display data from 11:00:00 till 11:59:59.

In PSQL query would look like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE time > ( date_trunc('hour',now()) - interval '1 hour' ) 
AND time <= ( date_trunc('hour',now()) ) ORDER BY time;
```

I was trying to use extract in similar fashion but I have no rows returned or error :/

Query below returns for example some narrowed data but it's like 2 hours each day from day one when database was started not last hour only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE extract(hour from cr_date) between extract(hour from now()) - interval 1 hour) 
AND extract(hour from now()) 
ORDER BY cr_date;
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved? or what I'm doing wrong in this query?

Answer (score 1):

Hour is only an integer, so it's finding any matches between , for example, 9 and 10, regardless of the date.

I would recommend

```
select * FROM data 
where cr_date >= date(now()) + INTERVAL hour(now())-1 HOUR
  and cr_date <= date(now()) + INTERVAL hour(now()) HOUR
```

date(now()) returns midnight, and hour(now()) returns the number of hours since midnight

so, at 11:10 am, it should result in a results between midnight + 10 hours (10 am) and midnight + 11 hours (11 am)

Comment: Good answer. One nitpick: the second half of the `WHERE` clause should be "less than" rather than "less than or equals": `and cr_date < date(now()) + INTERVAL hour(now()) HOUR`